# How to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\ln(n))^n}{(\ln(n+1))^{n+1}}$

Tags: limits

How would I solve the following limit

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\ln(n))^n}{(\ln(n+1))^{n+1}}$

Is there an intuitive way of solving it?

I have no clue on how to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that each term is positive and the fact that $\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)} <  \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$

Comment: I dont believe the limit is 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the squeeze theorem:

$$0<\frac{(\ln(n))^n}{(\ln(n+1))^{n+1}}<\frac{(\ln(n))^n}{(\ln(n))^{n+1}}=\frac1{\ln(n)}\to0$$

Comment: I could not find a simpler answer +1.

Comment: Simply Beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: No problem @Umuko

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

$$\ln (n+1)=\ln (n)(1+\frac {\ln (1+\frac {1}{n})}{\ln (n)}) $$
$$=\ln (n)(1+\phi (n)) $$
and
$$(1+\phi (n))^{-n}=e^{-n\ln (1+\phi (n))}$$

$$\ln (1+\phi (n))\sim \phi (n) $$

$$n\phi (n)\sim \frac {1}{\ln (n)} $$
the limit is $$1/\infty=0.$$

Comment: @Salalhamam_ Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\ln(n))^n}{(\ln(n+1))^{n+1}}\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}\right)^n\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac 1{\ln(n+1)}\right)
$

$\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}\right)<1$ for all $n>0$

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac 1{\ln(n+1)} = 0$

Comment: The third line is not correct. it is 1.

Comment: $1 - \dfrac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)} = \dfrac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)} \to 0$. So $\dfrac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)} \to 1$.

Comment: @DougM He probably meant inequalities are not preserved under limits.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I have corrected to something that I think is better.